# What type of microsoft studio shoud i used to create a commercial use application

Tags: visual-studio, licensing

maybe my question is silly, but i cannot find satisfy answer towards google,

I am trying to be a freelance programmer and create commercial use application using newest visual studio and sell it.

I try to be legal but end up confused, what type of microsoft visual studio should i use or buy?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first say: refer to the license for the product you wish to use, and potentially get proper legal advice based off the license in question.

That being said...  You can use any version of Visual Studio, including the free "Express Editions", to create a commercial software product.

The "higher end" versions add a lot of features, such as code analysis, etc - but even the free versions do not prevent making and selling software.